# Reading Template Field Label value thats bind to sqlDatabase Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to obtain the value from the Label Template Field which is bind to StudentID in the Student Table. I want to obtain the StudentID value and insert it into a different table.
Here is my Gridview and SQLDataSource:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" 
                        style="position:absolute; top: 232px; left: 311px;" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate >
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="AttendanceCheckBox" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="studentIDLabel" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                       
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [StudentID], [Name] FROM [Student] WHERE CourseID = @CourseID ">                         
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CourseDropDownList" Name="CourseID" 
                                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my code behind which inserts values into another Database Table:

```
protected void SaveRegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            int numRowsAdded;
            int id;


    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("AttendanceCheckBox")).Checked)
        {
           try
            {
                bool attendance = true;

                // Connecting to the database using the connection string in the web.config file
                connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                // Create an INSERT Sql statement
                // To prevent an Sql injection attack, we add parameters with names starting with an @ symbol
                command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Attendance(Present, StudentID, LessonID) VALUES(@Attendance, @StudentID, @LessonID)", connection);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attendance", attendance);
```

Can anyone help me with the code to insert the value inside the Label Template Field (StudentID) into the StudentID field in the Attendance Table. Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("AttendanceCheckBox")).Checked)
    {
Int32 StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row.FindControl("studentIDLabel")).Text)
....
....
}
```

Comment: What if the StudentID has the data type nvarchar? What is the C# data type for a nvarchar data type?